# distinct for sorting with ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, distinct, ransack

i was trying to sort values of a table with sort_link from Ransack. i found [an example](http://youcanlookitup.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/filter-search-pages-with-rails-sql-views-rans/) which is really helpful. but, i think i'm having problem with 'distinct'. i got this error 'ORDER-BY expressions must appear in SELECT list; DISTINCT'. 
my code looks like this :

```
q =user.joins(:buyer).order('users.name')
ransack = params["filter"]
@search = q.search(ransack)
@users = @search.result(:distinct=>true)
```

do i forget something? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As per [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748959/ransack-postgres-sort-on-column-from-associated-table-with-distinct-true) you might be able to solve this with an ActiveRecord joins query or select query to add the columns needed, for example:

```rb
q = user.order('users.name')
ransack = params["filter"]
@search = q.search(ransack).
            result(:distinct=>true).
            joins(:buyer).
            includes(:buyer)
@users = @search.all
```

Answer (score 0):

You have distinct as true. Ransack called the distinct value in the wrong manner with Postgresql, thefore you getting this error. If you use another database, you mostlikely would not.

So, if you make distinct false, you will not get this error. If you want to know why you need distinct, check out:

```
  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp
```

I am trying to find a way to include distinct if I need it. when I find out, I will edit this answer.