# using order_by expression and distinct true in rails 6 with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ransack

i am trying to achieve a very specific query and can't seem to find out how.

I am using ransack gem for filtering, and i have (distinct: true) set, because i want to Filter and Sort at the same time, which brings me problems i am trying to fix.

I have a model called A, A has a column called 'status'. 'status' can be 'approved', 'approved by manager', 'pending' or 'rejected'.

I want keep the database order default, but wanted to return it following the custom order

`STATUS_ORDER = ['approved_by_leader', 'pending', 'approved', 'rejected']`

for which i used this piece of code:

```
  def self.order_by_status
    ret = "CASE"
    STATUS_ORDER.each_with_index do |s, i|
      ret << " WHEN state LIKE '#{s}' THEN #{i}"
    end
    ret << " END ASC"
  end
```

Then, i just defined the scope:

```
scope :by_status_priority, -> { order(order_by_status) }
```

And this is the scope i use in my controller. This would work, except i want to keep `(distinct: true)` in ransack, to avoid duplicate results when using queries.

The error i get goes:

```
"PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list\nLINE 1:
```

I could use some suggestion in how to handle this. I need to keep (distinct: true) or have an alternative way of avoiding duplicates.

I will also be using nested sorting later on, which is something (distinct: true) can't work with, but that can be fixed by using includes and joins in my controller, so that won't be a problem. More about this here: [Ransack, Postgres - sort on column from associated table with distinct: true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748959/ransack-postgres-sort-on-column-from-associated-table-with-distinct-true)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @engineersmnky. Yes, the query is fine, that was just a mistake if mine. I've tried it using (distinct: false), and the scope works fine. What i'm having problem now is making it work with (distinct: true). I think i should be telling the query that 'state' is also a value for distinct, not just 'id'(default)?. I've suggested making a new column to set the priority, but my colleagues think we should find a better way.

Comment: @engineersmnky Honestly, your code is beyond my understanding right now (lol). I did try it, and i get this error:  `syntax error, unexpected local variable or method, expecting '}'\n...tatus).as(:status_order) )order(Arel.sql(order_by_status).as...\n...                          ^~~~~\n"`  I tried to fix it, but fixing something i don't understand shouldn't be that easy! I did spot a blank space before order

Comment: @engineersmnky I did try to fix it with the dot (and also, since status_order is a constant, also tried to set as(STATUS_ORDER) instead of :status_order) but i could not get it to work, this is what i get after adding the dot. (.) : `"no implicit conversion of Symbol into String"`. Any idea on what's wrong?

Comment: @engineersmnky How on earth did you come up with this? It... works. Would you please comment below, so i can mark it as solved? And if you have any suggestion on where i can read more on the subject, to fully understand the scope expression, that would be great, too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial suggestion is to create a `Status` model and table with `status` and `priority` columns and then create a formal relationship with your existing model as this will allow simple addition and reordering in the future without any code change.

I lieu of this, the error is fairly clear:

> for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

This means that when using SELECT DISTINCT you can only order by columns that appear in the SELECT clause

To solve this I would recommend the following:

- remove "ASC" from the `self.order_by_status` method (so that we can reuse the CASE statement
- then update the scope as follows

```
scope :by_status_priority, -> { 
  select(arel_table[Arel.star],Arel.sql(order_by_status).as('status_order') )
    .order(Arel.sql(order_by_status).asc) 
}
```

**TL;DR** Explanation of ActiveRecord and Arel

You will see `Arel` a few times in the above. [`Arel`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel) is the underlying query assembler for rails and offers a significant amount of flexibility allowing for much more composable queries.

Every `ActiveRecord` object exposes its `Arel::Table` via a method called `arel_table`. This part `arel_table[Arel.star]` will be assembled as "table_name"."*"  (select everything)

This part `Arel.sql(order_by_status)` will return an `Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral` which allows us to chain aliasing (as in `as('status_order')`) as well as ordering (as in `.asc`).

We could even build your entire CASE statement using `Arel` via

```
def self.order_by_status
  STATUS_ORDER.each_with_index.inject(Arel::Nodes::Case.new) do |cassette, (s, i)|
    cassette.when(arel_table[:status].eq(s)).then(i)
  end
end
```

This will allow you to get rid of the `Arel.sql` wrappers in `by_status_priority` (which are for raw sql strings) so the scope can now become

```
scope :by_status_priority, -> { 
  select(arel_table[Arel.star],order_by_status.as('status_order'))
    .order(order_by_status.asc) 
}
```

`ActiveRecord` provides a lot of convenience methods to expose the `Arel` query interface e.g. `select`, `where`, `order`, `joins`, etc. but it would be impossible to expose everything in such a simple way as to provide an easy top level DSL; however almost everyone of these "top-level" methods will accept `Arel` arguments without issue allowing you to build any query you could possibly want. If it is valid SQL then `Arel` can construct it.

Comment: This is awesome! I will definitely be digging deeper into Arel, it looks really powerful once you get the gist of it. Thank you for the long yet brief explanation. And for the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```rb
  STATUS_ORDER = ['approved_by_leader', 'pending', 'approved', 'rejected'].freeze

  def self.order_by_status
    STATUS_ORDER.map.with_index do |status, ordering|
      "('#{status}', #{ordering})"
    end.join(",\n")
  end

  scope :by_status_priority, -> do
    select("#{self.table_name}.*, status_ordering.*").
      joins("JOIN (values #{order_by_status}) AS status_ordering (status, ordering) ON #{self.table_name}.status = status_ordering.status").
      order_by("status_ordering.ordering")
  end
```

The idea is to have a virtual relation called `status_ordering`

| status | ordering |
| --- | --- |
| 'approved_by_leader' | 0 |
| ... | ... |

produced by `order_by_status` method
and to join it the original table.

The query should look like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME.*, status_ordering.* FROM TABLE_NAME
  JOIN (
    values ('approved_by_leader', 0), ('pending', 1), ('approved', 2), ('rejected', 3)
  ) AS status_ordering (status, ordering) ON TABLE_NAME.status = status_ordering.status
  ORDER BY status_ordering.ordering
;
```

And if you add `DISTINCT` it should still work as `status_ordering.ordering` is still in `SELECT` expression.

P.S. I haven't tested the code above.

Comment: Thank your for the suggestion. Your explanation is very clear and helps me undestand the approach, but it didn't work right off the bat, it has a small mistake somewhere which right now i don't have time to debug, but i do find your answer useful, so thank you. I chose the above answer by @engineersmnky, since it worked great too and helped me understand a little more of Arel.